# App crashes when logged in and navigating to other page

Tags: xamarin.forms, segmentation-fault

I'm working on an app and finally got the login system done lol

Now the following happens.

When I'm logged in I get send back to the main page. I check my menu, which should've updated to a hidden login button, a label that shows "Welcome {Username}" and a logout button. However, this doens't happen... Only after restarting the app this works.

Also, when I just logged in and haven't restarted the app yet and want to navigate to a different page, the app crashes and the console log the following:

https://hastebin.com/unaqurifeb.bash (I used pastebin cus the text got really long.)

Any idea as to what this could be?

Thanks!

Comment: appcenter.ms has free crash reporting tools that take about 2 minutes to add to your app

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Comment: But if you have the crash when developing, you can just use the debugger to find the problem.

Comment: @Daniel Yes and I've been going through the console, but the only error I could find was the one in pastebin...